# Vertica subquery with limit

Tags: vertica

I found problem in writing subquery with **limit 1** to get the top record.

Here is my problem example.

**Table Master(id,set)**

[image]

**Table Detail(id,set,code)**

[image]

i am trying to get the latest code for each set in **Master** table.

Following is the query which i tried but got an error that limit 1 is not supported for correlated subqueries and it should contain GROUP By clause.

```
select id,set,(select code from detail where set=master.set order by id desc limit 1) from master;
```

And the result wolud be like

[image]

please help me if this is wrong way, i am new to this vertica database.

thnk you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about that particular error, but you can use the `rank()` analytic function to produce results like this:

```
select id, set, code from (
    select M.id, D.set, D.code, rank() over (partition by D.set order by D.id desc) as rank
    from detail as D 
    right outer join master as M 
        on D.set = M.set) as ranks 
where rank = 1 
order by id;
```

The inner subquery uses the rank() function to assign a rank to each row within a set.  The outer query just picks out rows with rank 1.

Comment: Correct, you can use rank() or row_number()